# nginx sees dublicate http directive in .conf

Tags: docker, nginx

EDIT: The problem was solved by using a custom community image but that would not be an acceptable resolution for a proper app

Docker nginx container with this conf:

```
http{
    server {
        brotli_static on;

        listen 80;

        server_name domain.dev www.domain.dev;

        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root /var/www/certbot;
        }

        location / {
            return 301 https://domain.dev$request_uri;    
        }

        location /send {
            return 301 https://domain.dev$request_uri;    
        }

        location /projects {
            return 301 https://domain.dev$request_uri;    
        }

        location /picnames {
            return 301 https://domain.dev$request_uri;    
        }
    }

    server {

        brotli_static on;

        listen 443 ssl http2;

        
        server_name domain.dev www.domain.dev;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/domain.dev/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/domain.dev/privkey.pem;
        
        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html;
        }
        
        #since the backend is in the same docker network, i can use the container name as host
        location /send {
            proxy_pass https://aboutbe:8080;
        }

        location /projects {
            proxy_pass https://aboutbe:8080;
        }

        location /picnames {
            proxy_pass https://aboutbe:8080;
        }
    }
}
```

gives error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "http" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:26
```

So, i have a docker container serving a built react app.

Up to now i used the nginx:alpine image to build the container and it worked perfectly with the conf

```
    server {

        listen 80;

        server_name domain.dev www.domain.dev;

        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root /var/www/certbot;
        }

        location / {
            return 301 https://domain.dev$request_uri;    
        }

        location /send {
            return 301 https://domain.dev$request_uri;    
        }

        location /projects {
            return 301 https://domain.dev$request_uri;    
        }

        location /picnames {
            return 301 https://domain.dev$request_uri;    
        }
    }

    server {

        listen 443 ssl http2;

        
        server_name domain.dev www.domain.dev;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/domain.dev/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/domain.dev/privkey.pem;
        
        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html;
        }
        
        #since the backend is in the same docker network, i can use the container name as host
        location /send {
            proxy_pass https://aboutbe:8080;
        }

        location /projects {
            proxy_pass https://aboutbe:8080;
        }

        location /picnames {
            proxy_pass https://aboutbe:8080;
        }
    }
```

But i now want to get that sweet lighthouse green so i compressed the build with brotli.

To make it work with docker, my research led me to build a container with a pure alpine image and install nginx and brotli in it. installing brotli in a dockerfile using the nginx:alpine image did not work.

The moment i moved to a pure alpine, the conf without the http parent directive was a problem, which makes sense.

Can anyone see where i done goofed?